# MySql Stored Procedure Help

Tags: mysql

I'm writing some procedures in MySql rather than MS SQL, and I'm having a bit of a problem with syntax.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddUser
(
   IN pUsername Varchar(20),
   IN pPassword Varchar(16),
   IN pFirstname Varchar(20),
   IN pSurname Varchar(20),
   IN pEmail Varchar(50),
   IN pWebsite Varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO 
    users
    (Username, Password, Firstname, Surname, Email, Website)
   VALUES
    (pUsername, pPassword pFirstname, pSurname, pEmail, pWebsite);  
END;
```

This is the code I have come up with so far, just a basic add user proc, but I keep getting this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'pFirstname, pSurname, pEmail,
>   pWebsite)' at line 15

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma between `pPassword` and `pFirstname` in the line after `VALUES`.

Comment: Thanks, I've been staring at code way too long today!  although it still doesnt like the syntax lol

Comment: Seems using a different Delimiter helped.  Thanks for the help